# Запоминать время авторизации. Какие рекомендации?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. На сайте хочу сделать таймаут на ввод пароля.

Подскажите, а куда лучше записывать  и сверять логи эти неуспешных авторизаций:
Куки, база-данных , сессии ? Как я понимаю у каждого свои недостатки !
Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше всего - поставьте новую гугл капчу v2 (там просто кликнуть нужно) и не заморачивайтесь.
А ваши проверки все равно обойдут. Просто парсеры менее агрессивно кравлить начнут.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от желания использования данных логов.

- Если есть нужда в подальшим анализировании этих данных тогда уж точно
  в базу. (для долгосрочного хранения)
- Если для простой проверки количества авторизация тогда лучше в данную сессию. Ведь сессия должна жить время запроса а после обновляться через время. Куки же напрочь остаются на долго у пользователя (если он или вы их не удалите)

Так что можем сделать вывод что для временного хранилища информации мы можем использовать сессию, а для долгого хранения данных - базу данных.

Comment: Я рассматриваю блокировку от перебора паролей (брутфорсы). 
Хочу ставить небольшую заглушку.

ну так если атакующий не будет предоставлять сессионный идентификатор  ?

Comment: Тогда можно записать количество не успешных авторизаций конечно в сессию. Ведь куку можно очистить, а работать с сессией может только сервер.
И перед авторизацией проверять количество не успешных попыток.
Так же было бы хорошо создать время жизни этой сессии.
Laravel в своем случаи использует кэш.
[https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php](Laravel на GitHub)

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт в информационной безопасности, но допускаю вариант в кэшем и сессиями.
Прочитав как это реализовано в моем любимом фреймворке Laravel рекомендую:
Записывать в кеш попытку аторизации, индефицировать по md5 из логина (email или логин пользователя) Что затруднит но не избавит от брутфорса. Допустим лимит не удачных попыток для авторизации на данный email  = 5. И Время доступа к авторизации будет 60 секунд (или же больше все по усмотрению).
Проверяем на количество попыток если оно все еще равно 5, тогда проверяем на время, если оно больше 60 секунд чистим попытки и пропускаем.

Comment: > Ах да, если атакующий не будет предоставлять сессионный идентификатор тогда лучше его на сайт вообще не пускать

гугл-бота тоже не пускать из-за того что он без индентификатора сессии?